# How can I see what players type in commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am staff on a server and I need to be able to view what other people type in commands. I have already figured out private messages but not commands, thank you.

Comment: First, I already had a argument about this with an admin, not that it matters, but I strongly disagree with the PM matter. It's not public and if somebody wants to report it, they can copy and past it easily or show their own chat history, so for that reason not really something you need to be doing. That said, you can. The last time I checked the server logs unsuccessful commands but not successful ones. And for good reason, there's not much reason to know about successful commands, they worked. If you don't want a person to use a command, restrict them.

Comment: Ok, now, What have you tried? have you tried checking console logs? server logs? I know all of chat is logged. You'd probably need a plugin for that, and we can't recommend such things as it's not what we're here to do. You haven't even mentioned, are you running vanilla or bukkit or spigot or cauldron or ..........

Comment: These commands might be useful: `/gamerule doCommandBlockOutput true` will notify admins when a command block is used, and `/gameRule sendCommandFeedback true` makes all commands show up in chat. See the Minecraft Wiki for more information.

Answer (score 1):

That is easier with plugin called Essentials. When you have that intalled, edit configuration file at `plugins/Essentials/config.yml` and set socialspy-commands to `- '*'`. Then you can run command /socialspy and you see other's commands.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this you will have to either have the owner install a plugin or mod, or you will need to have access to the server jar if the server isn't a paid one (below)
[image: Server Jar]
<sub>(source: [thegond.com](http://www.thegond.com/gff/rp/minecraftservergui.png))</sub>
The owner is usually the only person that has this so you will need to ask the owner to somehow log this and send it to you.

Comment: BukkitGui is useful and is full-featured.

Comment: You don't even need the GUI; just look in the server log.